# ASP.NET - Error uploading/downloading files

Tags: asp.net

Just to give some initial context, i have an ASP.NET MVC application where the user creates an account, logs in and fills out a series of forms that he can save at any time. These forms are separated by different tabs. In one of the tabs, the user can upload and download JPEG and PDF files. This functionality has been implemented for a couple of weeks and at first, it was working perfectly. The files were uploaded with no problem and i could download them, open them and view their content without a problem. But lately, everytime i upload a PDF or JPEG file, when i download and open it, i always get an error. For JPEG files, i always get an error saying that the file type is not supported. For PDFs, i always get an error saying that the file failed to load. Keep in mind that i haven't touched this code since i first implemented and noticed that it worked.

Here's the code in question btw. The function above is responsible for uploading PDF and JPEG files. The other is responsible for downloading said files:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(Documento documento, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            int userId = (int)Session["userID"];

            using (LoginDataBaseEntities1 dbModel = new LoginDataBaseEntities1())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        if (this.IsJpeg(file) || this.IsPdf(file))
                        {
                            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                            MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
                            file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                            byte[] data = target.ToArray();

                            Documento doc = new Documento();

                            doc.Descricao = documento.Descricao;
                            doc.Nome = fileName;
                            doc.Ficheiro = data;

                            dbModel.Documentoes.Add(doc);

                            UserDocumento userDocumento = new UserDocumento();

                            userDocumento.UserId = userId;
                            userDocumento.DocumentoId = doc.ID;

                            dbModel.UserDocumentoes.Add(userDocumento);

                            dbModel.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Session["ErrorDoc"] = 1;

                            Session["SelectedTab"] = 4;

                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                {
                    Exception raise = dbEx;
                    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}", validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(), validationError.ErrorMessage);
                            raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                        }
                    }
                    throw raise;
                }
            }
            ModelState.Clear();

            Session["ErrorDoc"] = 0;

            Session["SelectedTab"] = 4;

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

    public ActionResult DescarregarDocumento(int id)
            {
                using (LoginDataBaseEntities1 dbModel = new LoginDataBaseEntities1())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Documento doc = dbModel.Documentoes.Where(dp => dp.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();

                        Response.Clear();
                        Response.Buffer = true;
                        Response.Charset = "";
                        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                        Response.ContentType = Path.GetExtension(doc.Nome);
                        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + doc.Nome);
                        Response.BinaryWrite(doc.Ficheiro);
                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();
                    }
                    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                    {
                        Exception raise = dbEx;
                        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                        {
                            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                            {
                                string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}", validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(), validationError.ErrorMessage);
                                raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                            }
                        }
                        throw raise;
                    }
                }

                Session["SelectedTab"] = 4;

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
```

Upon debugging, i noticed that the InputStream property of HttpPostedFileBase always returns empty hence why i keep getting these errors. I also got the following exceptions for the ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout properties of the InputStream:

```
+       ReadTimeout 'file.InputStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'    int {System.InvalidOperationException}

+       WriteTimeout    'file.InputStream.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'   int {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

Comment: I had an interesting bug in my code, where I passed the "file" variable around to other functions, similar to this.isJpeg and this.isPdf - when you open and read from an inputStream, it leaves the stream pointer at the end, and I had to seek back to the beginning again ie. file.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) - ideally you want to read the inputStream once into your bytes and use that in subsequent functions.

Comment: I tried to use file.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) but it didn't work. The file length is still 0 after it passes the this.isJpeg and this.isPdf conditions. However, i noticed that after commenting that condition (and the else clause), the file uploads and downloads without any problems.

Comment: ok, I'd imagine the isJpeg and isPdf functions could be closing the stream after use, and then not being accessible after they've been called?  Although, doesn't quite explain why it's been working on production for a bit; have these functions changed? do you have access to their implementations?